# Passing info into an entityform?

Tags: 7, entities

I am displaying a 'Contact Us' entityform in a lightbox (fancybox, specifically).  I need the entityform to send the admin the page that the user was browsing when they decided to contact us.

However, because I am displaying the form in fancybox via an iframe (in order to use drupal's ajax capabilities), my entityform is always loading from its own node - not the one I need to email the admins about.

Ultimately, I need to know how to get arbitrary info into an entityform.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the variables entityforms uses, but I'm wondering if there might be an option in there..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module? Entityforms just use Drupal Fields so I imagine it should work. You would then just define the values per field in the URL from your email.

> The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated
>   from the $_REQUEST variable.
>
> For example, the following URL,
>
> http://www.example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this is the title
>
> will automatically fill the Title field on a new blog post with the
>   words "this is the title". Any field can be prepopulated this way,
>   including taxonomy and CCK fields. You can prepopulate more than one
>   field at a time as well. Prepopulate is excellent for creating
>   bookmarklets. For examples on usage for all of these cases, please
>   read the USAGE.txt file that comes with the module or you can read the
>   online [handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/228167).